# very small php code for Password protected php page ,showing Undefined index:

Tags: php

Code listed below is working fine for me, but the problem is that if I  kept user & password 
blank, and press login button then I am getting below  error code:

```
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 6
```

Even if I kept wrong user id & password  then I get below error code:

```
Notice: Undefined index: r in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 6

Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.
```

Here `“Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.”` Is absolutely  right information 
I need all your helping hand to resolve unnecessary error code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("passwords.php");
if(isset($_POST['ac'])) {
if ($_POST["ac"]=="log") { 
if ($USERS[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]) { 
      $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["username"];
 } else {
      echo 'Incorrect username/password. Please, try again.';
 };
 };
 }
 if (array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) { 
 echo "You are logged in."; 
 header('Location: /dip01.php');
 } else { 
 echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" 

 value="log"> ';
 echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" />';
 echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" />';
 echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />';
 echo '</form>';
 };
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$USERS[$_POST["username"]]
```

when you leave the `username` input parameter blank, then it'll evaluate to:

```
$USERS[""]
```

what is a key that doesn't exist:

check for:

```
if(isset($_POST['ac'], $_POST["username"], $USERS[$_POST["username"]], $_POST["password"])) { /* ... */ }
```

instead of only checking for if sent:

```
if(isset($_POST['ac'])) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Hi, bwoebi , thanks for replay , I am very new , if you have time then  edit my code with your code . it will help for me.

Comment: @nur2544 Simply replace the line with `if(isset($_POST['ac'])) {` by `if(isset($_POST['ac'], $_POST["username"], $USERS[$_POST["username"]], $_POST["password"])) {`. That's all.

Comment: it works , but now i am getting another error like below Notice: Undefined index: logged in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 13

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: logged in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 13

Comment: This error on line 13 is most likely because `$_SESSION` does not contain the key `'logged'`. It's the same problem in a different array. See, you shouldn't access something in an array unless you're sure it exists!

Comment: @nur2544 Use instead of `array_key_exists(...)` simply `isset($_SESSION["logged"][$USERS])`

Comment: @bwoebi , Excellent job. Now it works perfectly. Thanks for your valuable time. take care.
Another issue , if I enter wrong password or user , it is not showing any notification. 
How ever  it is not mandatory for me , if it is then it looks like good!!

Comment: @nur2544 It should only show no notification if you enter the wrong user; when you enter the right user but the wrong password, there will be one.

Comment: @bwoebi ,  Brilliant. now everything is alright what I was looking for last 2 weeks !!. stay safe all time.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the fact that you're using the user input `$_POST['username']` as a key into the array `$USERS` without checking first that the key exists.

You could use `isset` to check that the key exists before accessing it, like this:

```
if (isset ($USERS[$_POST['username']]) && $USERS[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password'])...
```